# Read data content from an URL in a main with Dart

Tags: dart

In a main(), i would like to read a file from an url. It seams really easy to use the [HttpRequest from "dart:html"](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/HttpRequest.html) but it's not working from a command line :

```dart
import "dart:html" ;

main(){
  String url ="http://foo.bar/foo.txt";
  HttpRequest.getString(url).then((content){
    print(content);
  });
}
```

=>  The built-in library 'dart:html' is not available on the stand-alone VM.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Print the content:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  new HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('http://foo.bar/foo.txt'))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
    .then((HttpClientResponse response) => response.transform(new Utf8Decoder()).listen(print));
}
```

Or write it to a file:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  new HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('http://foo.bar/foo.txt'))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
    .then((HttpClientResponse response) => response.pipe(new File('foo.txt').openWrite()));
}
```

Comment: how to write it to an existing file like assets/app.txt

Comment: print is working but new file isnt created

Answer (score 8):

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

print(await http.read('https://example.com/foobar.txt'));
```

Easiest way

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Http package from Pub. http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http